# If H is a subgroup of a group G and K is a normal subgroup of G the show that K is a normal subgroup of HK.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Note K is a normal subgroup of HK

I thought I could just prove K is a subset of HK and vice versa so as to prove it a normal subgroup but then how to do this I have no idea because I keep getting hk element again while trying to do so.

I just tried to implement the steps to find HK is a subgroup of G.

Comment: You may want to include your thoughts or at least tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Problems like this are also how you practice proving normality. I didn't enjoy it at the time, but it's how you lear

Comment: $G$, $H$… and $K$? What happened to $I$ and $J$?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you know that $K \subseteq HK \subseteq G$, right? And you have $K \unlhd G$, so $gkg^{-1} \in K$ for every $g \in G$, $k \in K$. A fortiori, this holds for every $g \in HK$. Hence $K$ is a normal subgroup of $HK$.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably in a chapter of your textbook that showed $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $HK$.

Since $K$ is normal in $G$, you know $gKg^{-1} = K$ for all $g \in G$. For $K$ to be normal in $HK$, you need $gKg^{-1} = K$ for all $g \in HK$.

Can you stitch this together to make a proof?

Comment: @MattSamuel: Argh. I meant K. Fixed.