# Show that $K$ is normal in $HK$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group. Let $H$ and $K$ be two subgroups of $G$ and $K$ is normal in $G$.

Show that $K$ is normal in $HK$.

**My attempt**:

We will prove that:
\begin{equation*}
    \forall z \in HK, \forall k \in K, zkz^{-1} \in K
    \enspace .
\end{equation*}

Let $k \in K$. Let $z=h'k' \in HK$.

\begin{equation*}
    zkz^{-1} = h'k'k(h'k')^{-1}=h'k'k(k')^{-1}(h')^{-1}
    \enspace .
\end{equation*}

Yet, $\forall k, k' \in K, \enspace k'k(k')^{-1} \in K$. Furthermore, by assumption,
$K$ is normal in $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Therefore, $K$ is normal in $H$.

So,
\begin{equation*}
    h'(k'k(k')^{-1})(h')^{-1}  \in K
    \enspace .
\end{equation*}

which implies that:

\begin{equation*}
    zkz^{-1} \in K
    \enspace .
\end{equation*}

In conclusion, $K$ is normal in $HK$.

I'm really not sure about the fact that $K$ is normal in $H$. Could you confirm it?

Comment: This looks okay to me. What exactly aren't you sure about? You applied the definition of $K \triangleleft H$ correctly.

Comment: I was unsure about the fact that if $K$ is normal in $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $K$ is normal in $H$.

Comment: Ah. I think you have a typo in your first sentence (you mean to say that $K$ is normal in $G$ as an assumption?). In that case your question is answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593429/if-h-is-a-subgroup-of-a-group-g-and-k-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-g-the-show-that-k

Comment: Yes! Thanks a l ot!